# Collapsible [hamburger] menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am helping a friend of mine creating a collapsible hamburger menu for his site, but I am kind of stuck.. We have a deadline tomorrow, so we are a bit in a hurry..

This friend of mine, he created a menu structure based on div's, it works fine and the hamburger icon is showing up as wanted. What we want: when the screen size is under 1000px, the menu collapses. I know this way of creating a menu structure is not very normal, but I don't want to change a lot on the existing code of his project, since it is his source code.

I tried a collapsible menu like in this ([create hamburger menu in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246247/create-hamburger-menu-in-javascript)) post. In that case, i added a list, containing all of the hyperlinks and giving the homebanner a z-index, so that the menu would slide behind the image, but that does not work. Can anybody help me? Maybe we should use some javascript? Anyhow, a solution which would not affect the rest of the page would be very helpful.

This is the site HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>J&ouml;te Security</title>
        <link href="style.css" type"text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header"><img src="achtergrond.jpg" /></div>

        <div id="menu">

            <div id="nav-btn"></div>

            <a href="pagina1.html"><div id="button1">Homepage</div></a>

            <a href="pagina2.html"><div id="button">Algemeen</div></a>

            <a href="pagina3.html"><div id="button">Camera's</div></a>

            <a href="pagina4.html"><div id="button">Top<span>.</span>5</div></a>  

            <a href="pagina5.html"><div id="button">Test<span>.</span>Camera</div></a>

            <a href="pagina6.html"><div id="button">Werking</div></a>

            <a href="pagina7.html"><div id="button">Contact</div></a>


        </div>

        <div id="page">
                <div class="content"><br></br>
<h2><p> Homepage </p></h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p class="footertext">Copyright &copy; J&ouml;te Security 2016</p>
        </div>

      </body>
</html>
```

This is the site CSS:

```
body {
    background: #FFFFFF; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#dfe3ee, #FFFFFF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#dfe3ee, #FFFFFF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#dfe3ee, #FFFFFF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#dfe3ee, #FFFFFF); /* Standard syntax */
}

img {
width: 100%;
}

span {
visibility: hidden;
}

.navigation {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

img.header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

#header {
max-width: 70%;
margin: auto;
}

#button:hover { 
background-color: #bfbfbf;
color: #000000;
}

#button1{
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: Verdan, sans-serif;
max-height: 100%;
border-radius: 0%;
display: inline-block;
width: 14%;
background-color: #bfbfbf;
color: #000000;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
}

#button {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: Verdan, sans-serif;
max-height: 100%;
border-radius: 0%;
display: inline-block;
width: 14%;
background-color: #3b5998;
color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
}


#menu {
font-size: 0px; 
width: 70%;
background-color: #3b5998;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

#page {
color: #000000;
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
width: 70%;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: justify;
margin: auto;
padding-bottom: 300px;

}

.content {
max-width: 90%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

 .text {
max-width: 70%;
display: inline-block;


} 




.plaatjes {
max-width: 70%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 20px;
}
#footer {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: Verdan, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
width: 70%;
background-color: #3b5998;
text-align: justify;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-top: 8px;
margin: auto;
}

p.footertext {
text-align: center;
}

.picture{
height: 180px;
width: 180px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

   #button {
   display: none;}

#button1 {
   display: none;}

    #page{
   font-size: 14px;
}
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 1300px) {

   #button {
   display: none;}

.picture{
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}
    #nav-btn { 

background: transparent; 
border-bottom: 20px double #ffffff; 
border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
height: 6px; 
width: 25px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
    #page{
   font-size: 14px;
}
}
```

JsFiddle as asked: https://jsfiddle.net/2hupcdp1/ :)

Disclaimer: I did not create this website myself, a friend of mine did. So please don't comment I need to code properly.

Comment: You should **[post your code into a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)** and make sure it accurately displays the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a jsfiddle.